# Spring JPA - How can I make JpaRepository queries using an @Embedded property?

Tags: spring, jpa

I'm trying to make a `existsBy` query using a property that comes from an embedded class, but I'm receiving `"No property 'cpf' found for type 'Patient'"`.

The class Patient uses the Person class as embedded.

Person.java

```
@Embeddable
@Data
public class Person {
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 11)
    private String cpf;

    @Column(name = "full_name", nullable = false, length = 60)
    private String fullName;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String birthdate;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = true, length = 30)
    private String emailAddress;

    @Column(name = "cellphone_number", nullable = true, length = 11)
    private String cellphoneNumber;
}
```

Patient.java

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "tb_patient")
public class Patient  implements Serializable {
    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "patient_id")
    private UUID id;

    @Column
    private LocalDateTime registrationDate;

    @Embedded
    private Person Person;
}
```

PatientController.java (part of)

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<Object> savePatient(@RequestBody Person person) {

    if(patientService.existsByCpf(person.getCpf())) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CONFLICT).body("CONFLICT: CPF number is already in use!");
    }

    var patientModel = new Patient();
    BeanUtils.copyProperties(person, patientModel);
    patientModel.setRegistrationDate(LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("UTC")));
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(patientService.save(patientModel));
}
```

PatientService.java (part of)

```
@Service
public class PatientService {
    final PatientRepository patientRepository;

    public PatientService(PatientRepository patientRepository) {
        this.patientRepository = patientRepository;
    }

    public boolean existsByCpf(String cpf) {
        return patientRepository.existsByCpf((cpf));
    }
```

PatientRepository.java

```
@Repository
public interface PatientRepository extends JpaRepository<Patient, UUID> {

    boolean existsByCpf(String cpf);
}
```

***How can I pass the @Embedded properties to the @Repository?***

Answer (score 0):

You can try separate by `_` embedded filed name and it's filed.

```
@Repository
public interface PatientRepository extends JpaRepository<Patient, UUID> {

    boolean existsByPerson_Cpf(String cpf);
}
```